# C# Viewstate error in IE6 when using JQUERY

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer-6, viewstate

Whenever i try to submit a page using IE6. I get the error

```
System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
[FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +77
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +113
```

Whenever i do not include jquery, the form submission works on IE6. But when i include Jquery, it gets the error.
I have been trying to resolve this issue for about a week now but no luck. (I guess google hates me now) I tried disabling all the viewstate attributes on the Page element but no luck. :(

I'm thinking if i should code purely on javascript and ditch Jquery altogether but it's just unthinkable to abandon it at this point.

The system works perfectly on google chrome and firefox. I am yet to try it on IE7 and IE8.

I'm coding on Visual Studio 2005. Anybody out there who can help me?? TAT

Comment: strange... can you show us some code.. which page throws this error? and what kind of jquery script you have on the page?

Comment: Why are you worrying about IE6 for web development?  IE 6 is over ten years old and missing a bunch of features we take for granted in modern browsers.  IE 6's market share in the US is under 1%, and Microsoft has even put up a [site](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) devoted to convincing people to switch to a newer version of IE.

Comment: It's like if i embed jquery, i receive the error. Here are some of the scripts installed

Comment: I imagine one of the scripts modifies DOM element `__VIEWSTATE`. Are you going to show the scripts?